# Powershell: Create a Schedule Task into a Scheduled Task Folder; Path not found

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a scheduled task in a already existing scheduled tasks folder (UserSeparation), which is created under .

TaskPath switch keeps complaining "Register-ScheduledTask : The specified path is invalid." I have tried all combinations for but no luck. Any help?

```
# Test presence of folder
$scheduleObject = New-Object -ComObject schedule.service
$scheduleObject.connect()
$rootFolder = $scheduleObject.GetFolder("\UserSeparation")
$rootFolder | fl
Name : UserSeparation
Path : \UserSeparation


#####
$taskName = "TestTask1"
$user = "$env:USERDOMAIN\$env:USERNAME"
$password = "Passwrod"
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "notepad.exe" 

# Capture date & time for when the one time job will be scheduled
$timeinfo = Read-Host "Type TO Date in MM-dd-yyyy-HH-mm format"
$template = 'MM-dd-yyyy-HH-mm' #'HH mm yyyy dd MM'
$DateTime = [DateTime]::ParseExact($timeinfo, $template, $null)

# Create trigger
$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -At $DateTime

# Create settings
$Settings = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet -Compatibility V1 `
                -ExecutionTimeLimit ([TimeSpan]::FromHours(2)) `
                -DeleteExpiredTaskAfter ([TimeSpan]::FromDays(2)).Days

# construct task                
$inputObject = New-ScheduledTask -Action $action -Trigger $trigger -Settings $settings -Description "User Separation"


# Register the task in the folder
Register-ScheduledTask $taskName -InputObject $inputObject -User $user -Password $password -TaskPath "\UserSeparation"
```

Comment: What do you mean by "which is created under .which is created under ."? can you edit the question to be more clear?

Comment: @StillLearnin I think he means under `.` as in the root of the task namespace, hence his use of `-TaskPath "\UserSeparation"`.

Comment: `-Compatibility V1` are you sure, that V1 tasks support folders?

Answer (score 2):

I think that even though `\` is used when you want to refer to the root, if you are not referring to root, you should leave off the `\`:

```
Register-ScheduledTask $taskName -InputObject $inputObject -User $user -Password $password -TaskPath "UserSeparation"
```